# Bootstrap Form Helpers - Country Flag on Phone Input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-form-helper

I am trying to use the Bootstrap Form Helpers plugin for Jquery. Everything works fine, but I'm trying to use this example and show the country flag next to it by adding data-flags="true" but that's not working. Anyone has use this before?

http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/phone/#jquery-plugins  [EXAMPLE 4]

Comment: same problem here but on rails 4...data-flags="true" but no dice...

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this sorted..?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to use the `data-flags="true"` option combined with the phone input.

You can only add the `data-flags="true"` option on a `.bfh-selectbox` div element which cannot be linked to a phone input.

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true"></div>
```

Demo here: http://www.bootply.com/rP5zMMHWVo

Maybe it can be asked as a feature request to the project owner.